# Parse response from lambda

Tags: java

I want to use this code to make Rest API requests and parse the response:

```
Mono<PaymentTransaction> result = client.execute(transaction)
                    .doOnSuccess(
                            response -> System.out.println(response.transactionResponse
                                    + ", code = " + response.responseCode))
                    .doOnError(e -> System.out.println("Error " + e.getMessage()));
            result.block(Duration.ofSeconds(30));


private void parseRawResponse(PaymentTransaction result) {
        // do something     
}
```

How I can send the `result` to `parseRawResponse(PaymentTransaction result)` on `doOnSuccess`? I'm not aware in this case how to use the lambda expression.

Comment: Can you post an answer so I can mark your answer as correct answer?

Comment: `.doOnSuccess(response -> parseRawResponse(response)).doOnError..` does this answer work with you? I think I'm wrong I removed my first comment because I see this `result.block(Duration.ofSeconds(30));` after...

Comment: Yes, it's working.

Comment: It was just a shot, It's weird, but what about `result.block(Duration.ofSeconds(30));` ?

Comment: I will remove it.